# 400 Bad request error after starting Faye's messaging app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to follow the instructions on this following git link

https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-260/

It's one of the ruby on rails sample code I want to have a play and hack ruby on rails code (as I'm a RoR newbie)

After following the instructions ie downloading gem, installing faye etc, as soon as I opened up the page *localhost:9292/faye*, I couldn't retrieve any pages other than 'Bad Request'.  I googled this online to find possible solutions - but to no avail after 24 hours on it.  I'm not sure what I may have necessarily done wrong with the setup.

I did everything well in accordance with the instructions - so did it fail all of a sudden?

Here's the header response in the Google Chrome

```
Request URL:http://localhost:9292/faye 
Request Method:GET
Status Code:400 Bad Request
Request Headersview parsed
GET /faye HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9292
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,it;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
Response Headersview parsed
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Connection: close
Server: thin 1.6.1 codename Death Proof
```

I'm using ruby version 1.9.3p484

Any advice would be greatly much appreciated!

Andy

Answer (score 1):

If you followed the instructions of railscasts video. I think the page you opened up should be localhost:3000 , not localhost:9292/faye as you wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a look to the example from Github

```
curl http://localhost:9292/faye -d 'message={"channel":"/messages/new", "data":"hello"}'
```

We can see that the curl request is using a POST (-d) and is passing some parameters. When you tried with your browser you are requesting via GET and without parameters. Hence the 400 error you got.

Use curl or other http tool to make POST requests and passing the right parameters it will work.

Comment: Thanks Rafa.  I followed the link.  I replaced faye.ru with config.ru in the curl command.  It's a different error this time(but not any much worse).  It says 'The page you're looking for does not exist.'

Here's what's written in the log file.

I, [2014-02-16T16:24:55.576948 #6312]  INFO -- : Started POST "/faye" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-16 16:24:55 +1100
F, [2014-02-16T16:24:56.922025 #6312] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/faye"):
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'